# Нужно превратить в одномерный масив

Tags: javascript

```
 var arr = [
    ['Vasya'],
    ['Petya'],
    ['Sasha']
];
var arr2 = [];
console.log(arr2) // ['Vasya','Petya','Sasha']
```

Answer (score 4):

[`flat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat)

```js
var arr = [
  ['Vasya'],
  ['Petya'],
  ['Sasha']
];

console.log(arr.flat())
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
 var arr = [
    ['Vasya'],
    ['Petya'],
    ['Sasha']
];

let arr2 = [];

for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
 arr2.push( arr[i].join(' ') );
}

console.log( arr2 )
```